# Customizing D&D 5e to simulate Dark Souls universe

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, game-recommendation, house-rules

I want to simulate Dark Souls universe, where even a char lvl 1 is still dangerous to a char lvl 20, using D&D 5e as my starting point.

I though of several ways of doing this:

- Never level up HP.
- Level HP only by the minimum amount (1?).
- Set HP as max of hit die and only update it when CON mod updates.

What do you guys think, would this simulate Dark Souls? Do you think I should change other rules as well? Should I change anything related to attack, AC, damage? Any of this makes sense (haha)?

I want to use D&D 5e because it's simple and well balanced enough and because I still want players to level up and in general get better at their classes. I also want all the equipment from a medieval fantasy system (weapons, armors, etc.), and the combat system based on a d20.

Comment: Please don't keep trying to answer held questions by using comments.

Comment: Note after the edit: there's no such thing as "BAB" in D&D 5e, so suddenly switching the question from Pathfinder to 5e may not be as simple as you suspect. You might want to adjust the rest of the question to fit with how 5e works. The tags also don't fit anymore (and it's unclear what [game-recommendation] is doing there in the first place).

Comment: It seems more like you're trying to adapt Dark Souls' **game rules** in a meaningful way as opposed to its setting/lore. The calling card of Dark Souls is high lethality, and there are a large number of fantasy systems that do high lethality well. Consider making the question system-agnostic or asking yourself what you accomplish by making this question about D&D 5e.

Comment: You say you want 5e because its "well balanced" but, *you're intentionally trying to break it's balance.* As Lucas said, perhaps ask a new question: Either a game-rec looking for a system that can best emulate Dark Souls, or a system-specific question looking for high-lethality house-rules (while specifying exactly what parts of DS you want to incorporate).